# float* array to NSArray, iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, arrays, floating-point, nsarray

I have a float pointer array and I would like to convert it to an NSArray.

Is there a better way to do it than to iterate through the float* and add each entry to the NSArray?

I have:

```
float* data = new float[elements];
fill up data from binary ifstream
```

I want to avoid doing something like:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:elements];
for (int i=0;i<elements;i++)
{
 [mutableArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:data[i]]];
}
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:array];
```

Is there some convenience / more efficient method to copy a large chunk of floats into an NSArray?

Regards,

Owen

Comment: Why do you want to avoid creating the NSMutableArray?

Comment: I dont want to avoid creating the mutable array, I wanted some kind of convenience method that I may have overlooked such as [NSArray arrayWithFloatPointers:(float*)]. Obviously no such method is available.

Comment: `[NSArray arrayWithFloatPointers:(float*)]` is not standard, but you could write a category. Mind that you will need the size of the array, since the size of a dynamic allocated array in C cannot be calculated by the `sizeof` operand. A declaration would be something like this: `-[NSArray arrayWithFloats:(float *)buf size:(NSUInteger)size]`

Comment: Last line should be `NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableArray];`   , no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’ve got two problems: first, you can’t store a `float` in an `NSArray`, since `NSArray`s will only hold Objective-C objects. You’ll need to wrap then in an object, probably `NSNumber` or `NSValue`.

As to your original question, since you have to create the objects anyway, there isn’t a better method. I’d recommend the `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
    NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:floatArray[i]];
    [myArray addObject:number];
}
```

Keep in mind that `number` will be autoreleased. If you’re dealing with a *lot* of numbers, that can get out of hand pretty quickly with memory management, so you might do this instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
    NSNumber *number = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:floatArray[i]];
    [myArray addObject:number];
    [number release];
}
```

Comment: For that matter, why bother creating and filling `float[]` (ps. pick a better name that's not a reserved word!) when you can just create the `NSMutableArray` and fill that?

Comment: Jeff, If you read my code you will see im not trying to store the floats directly, I am wrapping them in NSNumber. Your "Answer" is basically what I already have posted.

Comment: Matt, I am using a float* as I am reading binary data from a file as part of a mesh loading class. The easiest way is with std::ifstream, using infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*> (data), sizeof(float * length); So I asked about an easier/more effiecient way of converting float* to NSArray (of NSNumbers in this case)

Comment: Also, Matt, Which of my variables is named the same as a reserved word. Surely not float* data.

Comment: @Owen, I didn’t see that code when I wrote my answer. Did you edit the post? Also, the reserved word you’re using is “float.”

Comment: Reserved word float? Im creating a float* and initializing it to an array of floats....  float* data = new float[size]; Data is the variable, float is the data type.... How is that using a reserved name. Im using a variable named data which is a float. How else am I going to create an array of floats without using the word float somewhere :s. Also, I edited the questions about 20 seconds after posting, as Opera removed the code tags, I had to re-ad them in internet explorer. I really want to know what you mean by usinga reserved word, /boggle.

Comment: Maybe my memory is faulty but I swear you were declaring `float* float` and using `float[i]`. But since there is no edit log of your question I will have to assume the former.